# Families of some columns

Tags: periodic-table

From previous lessons, I know that column 1 are alkali metals, column 2 are alkaline earth metals, column 3 till column 12 are transition metals, column 17 are halogens and column 18 are inert gases. But till now I don't know the properties of elements in columns 13, 14, 15 and 16... Are they metals or non-metals? I have not faced such a question before.

Comment: Are you asking for the *common names* of the groups e.g. Group 1 is commonly called "alkali metals", or are you asking for their physical properties i.e. whether they are metals, metalloids, or non-metals? To be honest, you can just look at the individual Wikipedia pages of the groups, or the elements to easily find your answer. The trend is that there is a general *increase* in metallic character going down the groups. So carbon is a non-metal, silicon and germanium are metalloids, tin and lead are metals.